# xslt 1.0 - Standardize/Sanitize Spaces based on a delimiter and then tokenize results (Vanilla XSLT Only)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have data, that I need to tokenize based on `" - "` notice the hyphen is surrounded by a space on each side, however, after parsing a hundred thousand rows, I noticed some of the data had a missing space around the hyphen, which breaks my logic.

I tried to use concat and substring, to find the broken hyphen and add in a space, but no matter what I try I can't solve all cases.  I think the best goal is to find all hyphens, and ensure there are is exactly 1 space on each side. However, I'm honestly completely open to suggestions.

EDITED, I need to solve this example.  I'm thinking either to add a list of safe words to the tokenization might be the easiest. However, I don't know how to go about it.

```
<part>
    <partDescription>Belden Gloves- Hi-Viz - Orange -Small</partDescription>
</part>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDF/1

```
<root>
    <!--99% of the 200k records are this first below record -->
    <part>
        <partDescription>Awesome Shirts - Chocolate/Black - Medium</partDescription>
    </part>
       
    <!-- However, there are a few hundred that didn't space the delimiter correctly 
         this causes my token template to not function as expected-->
    <part>
        <partDescription>Bantam Gloves - Chocolate/Black -Medium</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <partDescription>Belden Gloves- Black - Large</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <partDescription>Belden Gloves - Heatshield - Red- Small</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <partDescription>Belden Hats -Orange -Small</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <partDescription>XSLT Jacket- Black -Small</partDescription>
    </part>
</root>
```

Current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
                xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
                exclude-result-prefixes="php"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="part-by-product" match="part" use="productId" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="part">        
        <item>                

            <!--Struggling here :( -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeDescription">
                <!--<xsl:with-param name="text" select= "partDescription"/>-->
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select= 
                    "concat( substring-before(partDescription, '- '), ' - ', 
                            substring-after(partDescription, '- ') )"/>
            
            </xsl:call-template>
            
        </item>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Parse Description as Keys  -->
    <xsl:template name="tokenizeDescription">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:param name="partType"/>
        <xsl:param name="keys">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Heatshield')">short_name,benefit,color,size,</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>short_name,color,size,</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:param>
        
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($keys, ',')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeDescription">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="keys" select="substring-after($keys, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
   <short_name>Awesome Shirts</short_name>
   <color>Chocolate/Black</color>
   <size>Medium</size>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>Bantam Gloves</short_name>
   <color>Chocolate/Black</color>
   <size>Medium</size>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>Belden Gloves</short_name>
   <color>Black</color>
   <size>Large</size>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>Belden Gloves</short_name>
   <benefit>Heatshield</benefit>
   <color>Red</color>
   <size>Small</size>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>Belden Hats</short_name>
   <color>Orange</color>
   <size>Small</size>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>XSLT Jacket</short_name>
   <color>Black</color>
   <size>Small</size>
</item>
```

Actual Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
   <short_name>Awesome Shirts </short_name>
   <color>Chocolate/Black</color>
   <size>Medium</size>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>Bantam Gloves </short_name>
   <color>Chocolate/Black -Medium</color>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>Belden Gloves</short_name>
   <color>Black</color>
   <size>Large</size>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>Belden Gloves </short_name>
   <benefit>Heatshield</benefit>
   <color>Red- Small</color>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name/>
   <color/>
</item>
<item>
   <short_name>XSLT Jacket</short_name>
   <color>Black -Small</color>
</item>
```

Comment: Do you have a case where a hyphen is NOT a delimiter?

Comment: A hyphen should always be a delimiter.  However, it would be nice to have a flag as to whether the sanitizing process should be run, just in case.

Comment: If the hyphen is always a delimiter, then use it (alone) as the delimiter and get rid of the extra spaces using`normalize-space()`. I did not understand the "sanitizing" part.

Comment: I meant "Sanitizing" as in sanitizing the spaces around a delimiter.  I didn't know how to get normalize-space working as I kept deleting valid spaces between words.  How would I use this to not delete the valid spaces, rather only the spaces around the delimiter?    Then I could adjust the tokenize template to use "-" instead of " - "

Comment: Does https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDF/2 do what you want? Or can there be more than one space between words and you need to preserve them?

Comment: The `normalize-space()` function strips leading and trailing spaces and reduces runs of spaces to a single space. Unless you have runs of spaces that you need to preserve you should not have a problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks! The solution was blatantly obvious but I couldn't see it.  Can you post this as an answer, as it did exactly what I needed.  Michael, I tried using normalize space after the loop of keys, which was why it was stripping out the space that I needed.

Comment: It was Michael's suggestion that I spelled out there.

Comment: @MartinHonnen so, I ended up testing this, and I found words that break my theory.  I added a new example that breaks this.   Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  Let me know, if you have questions.

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="partDescription">
  <xsl:variable name="nodes">
    <xsl:call-template name="getNodesFromDelimitedList">
      <xsl:with-param name="inStrList" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'-'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>  

  <!-- *** NOTE *** Make sure you use your prefix to create the node set, not msxml.  -->
  <xsl:variable name="nodeList" select="msxml:node-set($nodes)"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(., 'Heatshield')">
      <xsl:element name="item">
        <xsl:element name="short_name">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nodeList/element[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="benefit">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nodeList/element[2]"/>
        </xsl:element>
 
        <xsl:element name="color">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nodeList/element[3]"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="size">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nodeList/element[4]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="item">
        <xsl:element name="short_name">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nodeList/element[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
  
        <xsl:element name="color">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nodeList/element[2]"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="size">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nodeList/element[3]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>          
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template name="getNodesFromDelimitedList">
  <!-- Delimited string with one or more delimiters.  -->
  <xsl:param name="inStrList"/>
  <!-- The delimiter. -->
  <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($inStrList,$delimiter)">
      <!-- Get the first element from the list.  -->
      <xsl:variable name="element" select="substring-before($inStrList,$delimiter)"/>

      <!-- Put the element in the list.  -->
      <xsl:element name="element">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($element)"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <!-- Call template to process the next element. -->
      <xsl:call-template name="getNodesFromDelimitedList">
        <xsl:with-param name="inStrList" select="substring-after($inStrList,$delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- Put the element in the list.  -->
      <xsl:element name="element">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($inStrList)"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: can you help me set this up in my fiddle?  The use of node matching goes over my head, unfortunately.

Comment: This code is one way to do what you ask for.  The only thing you have to resolve is the prefix for the node-set function as noted in the code.  Just backup your code, remove your key and templates, paste this in, fix the node-set prefix and you should be good.    Good luck!